# Change autoref name of items of a specific list

Tags: hyperref, lists

In my document I have a customized list `subtasks` type (using `enumitem`) to insert subtasks.
I would like to reference them using `\autoref`.
However, since these are lists, `\autoref` inserts the word "item" before the label, where I would like to have "subtask".

If I just use `\def\itemautorefname{subtask}` all items in all lists will be reference with the word "subtask".

Is there a way to only change the autoref name for items of the `subtasks` list?

Comment: Please post the code that defines the "subtask" enumerated environment. Better yet, please post a full MWE that shows what you've tried to accomplish so far.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't give you an answer for how to get `\autoref` to show "Subtask" instead of "Item". Fortunately, it's straightforward to provide a solution that uses the [cleveref](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref) package and its `\cref` cross-referencing command. With `\cref`, it's also easy to create multiple cross-references with a single command. (In the MWE, `hyperref` is loaded only to create hyperlinks, not to create cross-references.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{subtask}{enumerate}{1}     % this creates a dedicated counter named 'subtaski'
\setlist[subtask,1]{label=\arabic*} % set form of enumeration label here

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}      % 'nameinlink' option emulates look of \autoref
\crefname{subtaski}{subtask}{subtasks} % set prefix for items of type 'subtaski'

\begin{document}
\begin{subtask}
\item Uno \label{subtask:1}
\item Dos \label{subtask:2}
\item Tres\label{subtask:3}
\end{subtask}

A cross-reference to \cref{subtask:2}.

As stated in \cref{subtask:3,subtask:1}, \dots
\end{document}
```