# hyperref and cleveref together with enumitem

Tags: hyperref, enumitem, cleveref

I am working on lecture paper and I am referencing theorem-like environments a lot. I have written down a simple example how my layout might look like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    % references
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}    
    % theorem-like environments
\usepackage{amsthm}
    % languages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}

\usepackage{enumitem}
    % new theorem-like environments
\theoremstyle{definition}
    \newtheorem{_def}{Definice}[section]      

\theoremstyle{plain}
    \newtheorem{veta}[_def]{Věta}

\crefname{_def}{D.}{D.}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\begin{_def}
\label{sec:def:first}
First definition of this paper.
\end{_def}

\begin{veta}
First theorem with enumerate environment
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
    \item Item in the list\label{sec:th:li}
    \item Another item in the list
\end{enumerate}
\end{veta}

As you can see in \cref{sec:def:first} and together with \cref{sec:th:li}

\end{document}
```

The output of the example is this:

[image: Current result]

**The problem** is the reference to the item in the enumerate environment. I would like the `\cref` to print (the red boxes are not a problem, they aren't there since I wrote this output myself, that is without any referencing):

[image: Expected result]

Thanks!

**Additional question**

Is there a way of choosing, what form of name should `\cref` choose? For instance I would like to choose between:

[image: Additional question]

**Note A.** I am mixing two languages. Partially for you to understand, but also because I need it to work in my native language. Might seem like not a big deal, but I think that it was `\autoref`, which prints the name e.g. `Definition` which works neatly in English language, but not in my native - because for instance the suffix changes with the context.

Might seem like I care too much, but I think it is important. I am referencing theorem in mostly two ways:

- inside a sentence, where using whole word looks, I think, better - especially in mathematical texts, where there is no lack of symbols and abbreviations.
- above `=`,`==>`, etc. symbols in proof, equations,...

**Note B.** Sorry for the image quality, I followed the simplest procces: <kbd>prt sc</kbd> and then cut in `Gimp`.

Answer (score 5):

I think you can achieve your stated objectives by making two modifications.

- Insert the instructions

  ```
  \makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\p@enumi}{\theveta~}
  \makeatother
  ```

  in the preamble. This instructs LaTeX to "prefix" the value of the veta counter to the `enumi` (first-level enum) counter when constructing a cross-reference.

  Note that this approach will likely cause confusion if you use first-level enumerations in more places than just "vetas". If this happens in your document, you should probably "clone" the `enumerate` environment to create a new, dedicated enumerated environment that occurs only inside vetas. (For suggestions on how to clone enumerated environments see, e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/180192/5001.)
- Add the instruction

  ```
  \crefname{enumi}{V.}{V.}
  ```

  to the preamble as well. I think you can guess what it does.

Separately, remember that it's always a good idea to load `hyperref` and `cleveref` *last*. In particular, `cleveref` should be loaded after `amsthm`, but before you define any theorem-like environments (`_def` and `veta` in your case).

[image]

```
\documentclass[czech,a4paper]{article}
    % languages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel,lmodern}

    % theorem-like environments
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@enumi}{\theveta~} % prefix value of veta to enumi
\makeatother

    % cross-references
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}


    % new theorem-like environments
\theoremstyle{definition}
    \newtheorem{_def}{Definice}[section]      
\theoremstyle{plain}
    \newtheorem{veta}[_def]{Věta}


\crefname{_def}{D.}{D.}
\crefname{enumi}{V.}{V.}

\begin{document}
\section{First section}

\begin{_def}
\label{sec:def:first}
First definition of this paper.
\end{_def}

\begin{veta}
First theorem with enumerate environment
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
    \item Item in the list\label{sec:th:li}
    \item Another item in the list
\end{enumerate}
\end{veta}

As you can see in \cref{sec:def:first} and together with \cref{sec:th:li}, \dots

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Here's a modified solution that sets up a dedicated enumeration environment for use in `veta` environments, using the macros `\newlist` and `\setlist` of the `enumitem` package. One advantage of having such dedicated environments is that you don't have to mess with the basic LaTeX `enumerate` environment. Another advantage is that you can specify the form of the list labels and cross-references all in one fell swoop. Just the code is shown; the result will be identical to the screenshot shown above.

```
\documentclass[czech,a4paper]{article}
    % languages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel,lmodern}

    % theorem-like environments
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{venum}{enumerate}{1} % this creates a dedicated counter named 'venumi'
\setlist[venum,1]{label=(\roman*),
         ref=\theveta~(\roman{venumi})} 
% define appearance of labels and cross-references

    % cross-references
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

    % new theorem-like environments
\theoremstyle{definition}
    \newtheorem{_def}{Definice}[section]      
\theoremstyle{plain}
    \newtheorem{veta}[_def]{Věta}

\crefname{_def}{D.}{D.}
\crefname{venumi}{V.}{V.}

\begin{document}
\section{First section}

\begin{_def}
\label{sec:def:first}
First definition of this paper.
\end{_def}

\begin{veta}
First theorem with enumerate environment
\begin{venum}  % use 'venum' instead of 'enumerate' inside a veta env.
    \item Item in the list\label{sec:th:li}
    \item Another item in the list
\end{venum}
\end{veta}

As you can see in \cref{sec:def:first} and together with \cref{sec:th:li}, \dots
\end{document}
```

A personal comment on the advisability or desirability of creating separate dedicated enumeration-like environments for theorems, definitions, corollaries, etc. I can't think of a compelling reason for why it might be advantageous to have a potential multitude of such enumeration-like environments. Does it really enhance the readability and intelligibility of your document if you write "in V 1.2 (i)" instead of -- slightly more verbosely -- "in item (i) of Veta 1.2". As with almost everything else in life, being terse needn't be a virtue.

Comment: Well, looks like it gets the job done. But I am using first-level enumerations in different `\theoremstyle`s, since I am writing like 60+pages long paper. I need it in definitions, theorems, exercises, etc. You mentioned "cloning" the environment. Although I am not sure, how to achieve that precisely (possibly something like `\renewenvironment`?) do you think, it would be the right way to do that?

That is, if I understand corretly: "clone" the `enumerate` for each `theorem-like` environment, as you mention it for "vetas"?

Comment: By the way, any ideas for the additional question?:)

Comment: @quapka - I'll post an addendum that shows how to set up a dedicate enumeration environment using the methods of the `enumitem` package. On your additional question: Readers might forget quickly what "D" and "V" are supposed to mean. :-( I understand that Czech is a language in which nouns decline; the nouns (singular and plural forms) given in `\crefname` will in general only be correct for nominative cases. For other cases, have you considered using `\labelcref` instead of `\cref` -- and writing the appropriate noun forms yourself? Your readers may appreciate if you do this.

Comment: It is too late today to make a reasonable edit, but I will try to explain my situation bit more later. Nevertheless thanks a lot. I haven't used `\labelcref`, but I'll have a look at it.